# Does blender video editor have a histogram? How to appear it

Tags: video

My question is how i can appear the histogram in blender video editor?

example i am looking for something like this

[image]

Comment: i added an image, i am looking for something like that in order to fix the color see the over/underexposed etc.

i know blender have got something like this for images but what about for videos??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the a Video Sequence Editor window to 'Preview', a 'Display Mode' dropdown becomes available in its header.

[image]

On the right, the illustration shows a split into several VSE windows, with their Display Modes set to the options, and their headers hidden.

Now, if someone can tell me how to get rid of the little pan and zoom navigation icons, when there's no 'Gizmo' menu....

Comment: I followed what you said and it worked!
Thank you!!